# How to read and scan twitter's public timeline in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I'd like to read twitters public timeline scanning it for the occurence of a specific word. When someone says it, I'd like to automatically respond. Is this feasible using the twitter api? Where to start?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: That sounds like a great way to get people to try to find where you live and mail you a bomb. Perhaps you should be looking for someone with "Twitter Spambot Experience" on Elance.

Comment: I know it sounds like it. But I want to build a niche site, so it would happen less often than you might expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to decouple your Rails application from the traditional HTTP request-response cycle. What you probably want to do is implement a [background job](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2009/3/9/6-ways-to-run-background-jobs-in-rubyonrails/) which periodically calls the Twitter API and does something if the word you're looking for is found.

As for the actual Twitter API call you need to use, I suggest you start by looking at the [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).